# DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap performance issue

Tags: java, saml-2.0

Tuning java code for performance and found out that where I am creating `SignableSAMLObject` , the part `DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap()` is taking like `400 ms`. Does anybody have any notes on why this takes longer time than rest of unmarshalling part of code (which takes around 10 ms)? How this can be optimized for performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap()` only once in your application, say on startup. So it's performance should not be a problem